# How do I make my drop down select menu persistently show the same data after a query is done using the menu?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

So I am having an issue with a drop down selection box.  What I am doing is having someone log into a database, and then the database shows all the tables available in the selection box.  The user can then select the table they wish to see, hit select and bam! There's the table information.

I am, however having an issue getting the data in the selection box to persist after they hit select. For some reason, it just makes it empty.  I'm using session variables, and maybe that effects it?  I'm just now beginning to learn how that works too.  Take a look at let me know what you think:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['session_level'])):
    $_SESSION['session_level'] = 0; ?>
<? endif ?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['host'])):
    $_SESSION['host'] = $_POST['host'];
    $_SESSION['dbname'] = $_POST['dbname'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['pw'] = $_POST['pw'];
?>
<?php endif ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Login Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <?  
        if (isset($_POST['return']))
        {
            $_SESSION['session_level'] = 0;
        }
        else if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {   
            try
                {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$_POST['host'].";dbname=".$_POST['dbname'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['pw']);  

                }
            catch(Exception $error)
                {
                $_SESSION['session_level'] = 0;?>
                    <a href='<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>'>Click here to return.</a> 
                    <? echo "\n"; ?>
                <?die("Connection to user database failed: " . $error->getMessage());

                }
            try
                {
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO:: ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $query = "SHOW TABLES";
                $results = $db->query($query)->fetchAll();
                $_SESSION['session_level'] = 1;
                }
            catch(Exception $error)
                {
                    echo "Problem with query!";
                    $_SESSION['session_level'] = 0;?>
                <a href='<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>'>Click here to return.</a> 
            <?  }
        }
        ?>
        <?php if($_SESSION['session_level'] == 0){?>
        <h1>Database Practice</h1>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name='initialentry'>
            <table border='0' style='text-align: center'>
                <tr>
                    <td style='text-align: right;'>Enter host name:</td>
                    <td style='text-align: left;'>
                    <input type='text' name='host' value='localhost'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style='text-align: right;'>Enter database name:</td>
                    <td style='text-align: left;'>
                    <input type='text' name='dbname' value='zxyx999'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style='text-align: right;'>Enter user name:</td>
                    <td style='text-align: left;'>
                    <input type='text' name='username' value='zxyx999'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style='text-align: right;'>Enter password:</td>
                    <td style='text-align: left;'>
                    <input type='password' name='pw' width='15' value='12345'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style='text-align: right;'><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"></td>
                    <td style='text-align: left;'><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
<?php }


else if ($_SESSION['session_level'] == 1)
{
    ?>

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name='getForm'>
            <select name='select'>
                <? foreach($results as $row)
                    echo "<option value=" . $row[0] .">" .$row[0]. "</option>"; ?> 
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="selected" value="Select">
            <input type="submit" name="return" value="Return to Main Screen">           
        </form>
    <?php   


    if(isset($_POST['selected']))
    {
        try
        {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$_SESSION['host'].";dbname=".$_SESSION['dbname'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['pw']);
        }
        catch(Exception $error)
        {
            die("Connection to user database failed: " . $error->getMessage());
        }

        try
        {
            $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $_POST['select']);
            $query->execute();
            $header = true;
        }
        catch(Exception $error)
        {
            echo "Query failed.";
        }
        echo "</br>";

        ?>

        <?php

        echo "<table border='1'>";

        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            if($header == 'true')
            {
                foreach($row as $index => $fieldValue)
                {
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $index;
                    echo"</td>";
                }
            echo "</tr>";
            $header = 'false';  
            }

            echo "<tr>";
            foreach($row as $index => $fieldValue)
            {
                echo "<td>";
                echo $fieldValue;
                echo "</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";

    }
}

        ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you repopulate the select list, if the option selected matches the option being populated, then you can make that bit of code `<option selected value="` and that option will now be the default selected item at the moment.

I realize the below code isn't PHP, my point is that it should be a simple If statement, to include the `selected` tag into the option.

```js
/*

Adding the "selected" tag to an option, makes it the default.

*/
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="" style="display:none;">Select a Value</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<select>
    <option value="" style="display:none;">Select a Value</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3" selected>3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I added that, but it still didn't show anything after I displayed a table.

Comment: I want to make sure I'm understanding correctly. There's a form that a user logs into. Once past that, there's another form with a select box, allowing the user to choose an option. Once chosen, the user submits THAT form. The page then reloads and shows the information requested, and you want the select box to still be what the user selected.

Comment: I want it to still be what the user selected, and I want them to be able to choose another option as well.

Comment: Exactly... so you'll loop through all the options, using the code you already have, with the added code of an `if` statement that "If the current option in the loop, matches the option that was initially selected, then add the tag 'selected' to the option."

Comment: I know this isn't what you're asking for, but personally, I would use jQuery and AJAX to access the data. That way the data will be updated, but the page never has to be refreshed. You would still use PHP to get and send data to your DB, but the AJAX would be able to make those requests on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand your problem then my advice 'll be to change your form and do it this way :

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name='getForm'>
        <input type="hidden" name="selected" value="true">
        <select name='select'>
            <? foreach($results as $row)
                echo "<option value=" . $row[0] .">" .$row[0]. "</option>"; ?> 
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name='getForm'>
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="true">
        <input type="submit" value="Return to Main Screen">
</form>
```

It means you must create 2 forms instead of 1 with because the `name` value on a `submit` button is not intrepreted the same way on all browser. So by removing and replacing it by an input type `hidden` it 'll assure the field 'll exist after submitting forms.

Comment: The drop down is still blank after I hit submit and output a table :/

Comment: By dropdown you mean `<select name="select">` ? Moreover by "blank" you meand there no options inside or no option "pre-selected" ?

Comment: Thats correct. There is no ability to select anything. It makes me think that the SHOW TABLES query is not being reactivated. But I am not sure why.

Comment: It means there is an error. But its displayed inside your select. If you have `firebug` plugin on your browser inspect your select. It 'll reveal your error. If you havent `firebug`, I highly suggest you to install it ;)

Comment: Oh, this is fancy as heck.  So, I ran `firebug` and checked the script area.  It says `Access to restricted URI denied.`.  Is this the correct section, and if so, does this error make sense to you?

Comment: So I checked the html source following this.  It shows me an undefined variable inside of the Select area. Why would the variable be undefined?